# Telegram Bot Payment doesn't work with Apple Pay

Tags: stripe-payments, telegram-bot

I made a bot which accepts payment via the telegram payment api.
I connected the bot with stripe and it works fine with credit cards,
but I get an 'Apple Pay Is Not Available in "Telegram"' error message if I try to
pay with Apple Pay.

Is there any extra step I have to take than just connecting stripe via the Stripe Bot ? Do I have to activate Apple Pay in Stripe ?

Comment: I think this is more something to do with Telegram's app itself than the bot : https://github.com/TelegramMessenger/Telegram-iOS/issues/225 , maybe related to the Privacy and Security settings for it on your device.

Comment: already checked that one.. it's not the same issue

Answer (score 0):

The information related to the payment bot is available here on the [Bot Payments API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/payments) page. Check if this helps.

Comment: used that to create the bot, but there aren't any extra details for apple pay or something that could help with the problem